# Getting all projects that the user has access tol

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to get a list of all projects that a user has access to. To get all projects I would need all hubs, but I'm only getting the hub of the user's organisation so I only can get projects hosted by that organisation.
Is there a way to get all projects that the user has access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your **Forge app** you can get a list of **all the hubs** that
(1) the user has access to **AND** (2) your **Forge app** has been **provisioned** for

In the reply from the `GET /hubs` [endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/) you'll get information about which of the above two are missing - see [Errors when retrieving hubs](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/errors-when-retrieving-hubs)

And here is info on how to provision your **Forge app** for a given **BIM 360**/**ACC** account: [BIM 360 Docs Provisioning for Forge Apps](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360-docs-provisioning-forge-apps)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was afraid that's the case. I was hoping to develop an app for a client to do some data design automation on their models but they have about 200 projects and most of them hosted by others. It would take months to provision an app for all external hubs with no guarantee on 100% coverage.